# Mysql - Is separate db for static data tables suggested?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have bunch of tables (around 20) which rarely change which I am calling static data. These are look up tables.

I am thinking to store them in a separate db. Would there be any performance issues considering they are referenced (foreign key constraint) is many main tables in another database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep them in the same database with the tables that are referencing them. There's really very little to be gained by placing them in a separate DB.

Comment: I will go for it even if there is small advantage. Can you put some light on pros cons, please?